# Pygit2: How to unstage a file?

Tags: python, git, pygit2

In pygit2, if I stage the adding or removing of a file, how can I unstage them like I'd do with `git reset`?

I need to use pygit2 to accomplish the following git actions:

```
git reset HEAD
git checkout .
```

I can checkout with

```
repo = pygit2.Repository(target_dir)
repo.checkout('HEAD')
```

but I don't know how to do the reset action.

Thanks

Comment: http://www.pygit2.org/repository.html#pygit2.Repository.reset